# Create a new string that will consist of common letters from other two strings

Tags: c, string, letters

I'm new to C programming. I have a task to do.
User inputs two strings. What I need to do is to create a new string that will consist only from common letters of those two given strings.
For example:
if given:

```
str1 = "ABCDZ"
str2 = "ADXYZ"
```

the new string will look like: `"ADZ"`.
I can't make it work. I think there must be a better (more simple) algorithm but I have waisted too much time for this one so I want to complete it .. need your help!

what I've done so far is this:

```
char* commonChars (char* str1, char* str2)
{
    char *ptr, *qtr, *arr, *tmp, *ch1, *ch2;
    int counter = 1;
    ch1 = str1;
    ch2 = str2;
    arr = (char*) malloc ((strlen(str1)+strlen(str2)+1)*(sizeof(char))); //creating dynamic array
    strcpy(arr, str1);
    strcat(arr,str2);
    for (ptr = arr; ptr < arr + strlen(arr); ptr++)
    {
        for (qtr = arr; qtr < arr + strlen(arr); qtr++) // count for each char how many times is appears
        {
            if (*qtr == *ptr && qtr != ptr)
            {
                counter++;
                tmp = qtr;
            }
        }
        if (counter > 1)
        {
            for (qtr = tmp; *qtr; qtr++) //removing duplicate characters
                *(qtr) = *(qtr+1);
        }
        counter = 1;
    }
    sortArray(arr, strlen(arr)); // sorting the string in alphabetical order
    qtr = arr;
    for (ptr = arr; ptr < arr + strlen(arr); ptr++, ch1++, ch2++) //checking if a letter appears in both strings and if at least one of them doesn't contain this letter -  remove it
    {
        for (qtr = ptr; *qtr; qtr++)
        {
            if (*qtr != *ch1 || *qtr != *ch2)
                *qtr = *(qtr+1);
        }
    }
}
```

Don't know how to finish this code .. i would be thankful for any suggestion!

Comment: I noticed your example the letters appeared in order.  Examples: "ADZ" -> "AZ" = "AZ" obviously.  But  "ZDA" -> "AZ" could be "AZ" "ZA" or ""

Comment: what could be the output if a letter is repeated 2 times? example `str1 = "AABCDZ"` and `str2 = "ADXYZ"`

Comment: Does uppercase and lowercase are taken account? what could be the output of the following strings example `str1 = "ABCDZ"` and `str2 = "adxyz"` ?

Comment: True.Both two strings sorted alphabetically. That was underlined in my exercise.

Comment: Oh and yes! each letter appears only once!

Comment: you can use [strchr()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/) it makes your algorithm easier

Comment: [Don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169)

Comment: Guys,thanks for the replies..but all I needed is  an algorithm for  this: I have string: str1 = "ABCDXYZ". 
Also I have these two strings: str2 = ABCDZ and str3 = ADXYZ. I want to remove from "ABCDXYZ"  every letter that doesn't appear in both str2 and str3 so that str1 will look like this: "ADZ" without using **strchr** function.
I thought about something like this:

    qtr = arr;
    for (ptr = arr; ptr < arr + strlen(arr); ptr++, ch1++, ch2++)
    {
     for (qtr = ptr; *qtr; qtr++)
     {
      if (*qtr != *ch1 || *qtr != *ch2)
       *qtr = *(qtr+1);
     }
    }
but it doesn't work ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define min(x,y) ((x)<(y)? (x) : (y))

char* commonChars (const char *str1, const char *str2){
    //str1, str2 : sorted(asc) and unique
    char *ret, *p;
    int len1, len2;
    len1=strlen(str1);
    len2=strlen(str2);
    ret = p = malloc((min(len1, len2)+1)*sizeof(char));

    while(*str1 && *str2){
        if(*str1 < *str2){
            ++str1;
            continue;
        }
        if(*str1 > *str2){
            ++str2;
            continue;
        }
        *p++ = *str1++;
        ++str2;
    }
    *p ='\0';

    return ret;
}

char *deleteChars(const char *str, const char *dellist){
    //str, dellist : sorted(asc) and unique
    char *ret, *p;
    ret = p = malloc((strlen(str)+1)*sizeof(char));

    while(*str && *dellist){
        if(*str < *dellist){
            *p++=*str++;
            continue;
        }
        if(*str > *dellist){
            ++dellist;
            continue;
        }
        ++str;
        ++dellist;
    }
    if(!*dellist)
        while(*str)
            *p++=*str++;
    *p ='\0';

    return ret;
}

int main(void){
    const char *str1 = "ABCDXYZ";
    const char *str2 = "ABCDZ";
    const char *str3 = "ADXYZ";
    char *common2and3;
    char *withoutcommon;

    common2and3 = commonChars(str2, str3);
    //printf("%s\n", common2and3);//ADZ
    withoutcommon = deleteChars(str1, common2and3);
    printf("%s\n", withoutcommon);//BCXY

    free(common2and3);
    free(withoutcommon);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The output array cannot be longer that the shorter of the two input arrays.
You can use `strchr()`.

```
char * common (const char *in1, const char *in2) {
    char *out;
    char *p;

    if (strlen(in2) < strlen(in1)) {
        const char *t = in2;
        in2 = in1;
        in1 = t;
    }

    out = malloc(strlen(in2)+1);
    p = out;
    while (*in1) {
        if (strchr(in2, *in1)) *p++ = *in1;
        ++in1;
    }
    *p = '\0';
    return out;
}
```

This has O(`N`x`M`) performance, where `N` and `M` are the lengths of the input strings. Because your input is alphabetical and unique, you can achieve O(`N`+`M`) worst case performance. You apply something that resembles a merge loop.

```
char * common_linear (const char *in1, const char *in2) {
    char *out;
    char *p;

    if (strlen(in2) < strlen(in1)) {
        const char *t = in2;
        in2 = in1;
        in1 = t;
    }

    out = malloc(strlen(in2)+1);
    p = out;
    while (*in1 && *in2) {
        if (*in1 < *in2) {
            ++in1;
            continue;
        }
        if (*in2 < *in1) {
            ++in2;
            continue;
        }
        *p++ = *in1;
        ++in1;
        ++in2;
    }
    *p = '\0';
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I'm not fully understood neither the first nor the second examples you provided.  I just need the algorithm to solve this: I have string: str1 = "ABCDXYZ". Also I have these two strings: str2 = ABCDZ and str3 = ADXYZ. I want to remove from "ABCDXYZ" every letter that doesn't appear in both str2 and str3 so that str1 will look like this: "ADZ" without using strchr function.

Comment: What you describe in your comment is not what you describe in your question, nor does it match the inputs to your `commonChars()` function. You only provide 2 inputs, not 3. Can you clarify how my second function does not satisfy your request?

Answer (score 0):

I will do something like this :

```
char*   commonChars(char* str1, char* str2) {
   char*  ret = malloc(strlen(str1) * sizeof(char));
   int    i = j = k = 0;

   for (; str1[i] != '\n'; i++, j++) {
       if (str1[i] == str2[j]) {
          ret[k] = str1[i];
          k++;
       }
    }
  ret[k] = '\0';
  ret = realloc(ret, k);
  return ret;
}
```

It's been a while i didn't do C, hope this is correct

Comment: it's forbidden for me to use the realloc  function in this exercise :/ but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the weird use of char arrays, was just trying to get it done fast.  The idea behind the algorithm should be obvious, you can modify some of the types, loop ending conditions, remove the C++ elements, etc for your purposes.  It's the idea behind the code that's important.

```
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


bool isCharPresent(char* str, char c) {
    do {
        if(c == *str) return true;
    } while(*(str++));

    return false;
}

int main ()
{
    char str1[] = {'h', 'i', 't', 'h', 'e', 'r', 'e', '\0'};
    char str2[] = {'a', 'h', 'i', '\0'};
    string result = "";

    char* charIt = &str1[0];

    do {
        if(isCharPresent(str2, *charIt))
            result += *charIt;
    } while(*(charIt++));


    cout << result << endl; //hih is the result.  Minor modifications if dupes are bad.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use strpbrk() function, to do this job cleanly.

```
const char * strpbrk ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );
char * strpbrk (       char * str1, const char * str2 );
```

Locate characters in string
Returns a pointer to the first occurrence in str1 of any of the characters that are part of str2, or a null pointer if there are no matches.

The search does not include the terminating null-characters of either strings, but ends there.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] = "ABCDZ";
  char key[] = "ADXYZ";

  char *newString = malloc(sizeof(str)+sizeof(key));
  memset(newString, 0x00, sizeof(newString));

  char * pch;
  pch = strpbrk (str, key);

  int i=0;
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
     *(newString+i) = *pch;
     pch = strpbrk (pch+1,key);
     i++;
  }

  printf ("%s", newString);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So i found the solution for my problem. Eventually I used another algorithm which, as turned out, is very similar to what @**BLUEPIXY** and @**user315052** have suggested. Thanks everyone who tried to help! Very nice and useful web source!

Here is my code. Someone who'll find it useful can use it. 
Note: 
(1) str1 & str2 should be sorted alphabetically;
(2) each character should appear only once in each given strings;

```
char* commonChars (char* str1, char* str2)
{
    char *ptr, *arr,*ch1, *ch2;
    int counter = 0;
    for (ch1 = str1; *ch1; ch1++)
    {
        for(ch2 = str2; *ch2; ch2++)
        {
            if (*ch1 == *ch2)
                counter++;
        }
    }
    arr =  (char*)malloc ((counter+1) * sizeof(char));
    ch1 = str1;
    ch2 = str2;
    ptr = arr;
    for (ch1 = str1; *ch1; ch1++,ch2++)
    {
    while (*ch1 < *ch2)
    {
        ch1++;
    }
    while (*ch1 > *ch2)
    {
        ch2++;
    }
    if (*ch1 == *ch2)
    {
        *ptr = *ch1;
        ptr++;
    }
    }
    if (ptr = arr + counter)
        *ptr = '\0';
    return arr;

}
```